# Private build for CI/CD workflows

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery

I am looking for recommendations or best practices to implement private builds in CI/CD.  When developers check in code to a "private branch" or a personal workspace in source control it should trigger CI / CD workflows in Jenkins.  It should be separate from the CI/CD workflows which are executed off trunk or main branch in SCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Multi-branch pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) as explained [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/). It will build every branch separately. However, if there are any shared external resources(updating file/DB) they should be [locked](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/).